# Setup backup with mirror image

Tags: backup, windows-backup

I need to generate backup from my pc/server.
But condition is if my first backup drive damage than I am able to use second drive for restore.

I guess for that I need to use mirror backup, but how to do, which is no in my mind...

Any other batter Idea will also good....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could backup to a NAS (Network Attached Storage) that has two harddrives in a RAID1 array. However, that is mainly trying to answer your particular question, but maybe not the best solution for your "problem".

A more simple approach would be using two external harddrives and a backup software that gives you one single file from your backup and simply manually copy that file over to the second drive.